# Connecting to Git repo on own web server with SSH

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have 2 web servers. On server A I have a `GitLab` installed.

On server B I just initialized a bare Git repo.

Now I want to automatically push the GitLab repo to server B using [GitLab's remote repository mirror function](https://gitlab.com/help/workflow/repository_mirroring#pushing-to-a-remote-repository)

For this I need an HTTPS or SSH url, and I want to do it with SSH.

**Question 1:** What is the url I need to insert there? I guess it should be something like `ssh://ssh-user@server-b.com:path-to-git-repos/project.git`. Is that right?

**Question 2:** Since the user connecting to the url is GitLab's Git user, I guess I need to create an own SSH key for this user and add the public key to my web server. How can I do this since the Git user has no permissions to do anything except from Git commands on terminal level? I guess I need to create it with the root user of my GitLab server, but how do I do that? I can't even find the Git user's home dir when I'm connected as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh://ssh-user@server-b.com:path-to-git-repos/project.git` is the correct URL if `path-to-git-repos/project.git` is owned by user ssh-user, and if there is no other Git hosting services.

> Since the user connecting to the url is GitLab's Git user, I guess I need to create an own SSH key for this user and add the public key to my web server.

Yes, a dedicated private/public ssh key pair needs to be created, with the public one going to serverB `~ssh-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`: you can copy it yourself.
Check `ps -eaf|grep gitlab` on server A: you will see which account is running GitLab.
Creates your SSH keys in the account `~/.ssh` folder.

From the comments, the trick was:

- to generate ssh key pairs from the root account, and move the keys to `~git/.ssh`
- to copy `~git/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` over to `serverB`, `~ssh-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- to test the ssh connection from the root account (since the git account is limited to GitLab command)

  ```
  ssh -i ~git/.ssh/id_rsa ssh-user@serverB
  ```

That has the side effect to fill out the `~root/.ssh/known_hosts` file, that can then be copied over to `~git/.ssh/known_hosts`

- to use the SSH URL:

  ```
  ssh://ssh-user@server-b.com/absolute/path-to-git-repos/project.git
  ```

And the mirroring can start working.

Comment: Ok, then my thoughts were right. I found the home dir of the git user by typing `echo ~git` which is actually `/var/opt/gitlab`. But when I'm connected with the root user, cd to `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh`, execute `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and choose `git` as name, it still creates a key for the root user (when I check `/var/opt/gitlab/git.pub` it ends with `root@server-a`). How can I generate an SSH key for the git user there?

Comment: @Froxx the end of your key does not matter. What matter is that it is owned by git, with `chmod 600` as right, and has the default name `id_rsa`. And that `id_rsa.pub` content is copied over serverB as I mentioned. Then it *might* work, unless GitLab decide to enforce what its documentation says, namely that the repository must be accessible by `http://` or `https://` or `git://`.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to access with `ssh://` the docs are not up-to-date. In the actual frontend it says `The repository must be accessible over http://, https://, ssh:// or git://.`. But there is still something that's not correct. I renamed both files in `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/` from `git` to `id_rsa` (with mv command), added the public key to server B's authorized keys, and tried entering the SSH url with both paths to the git repo – absolute and relative to the ssh-user's home dir. Both don't work. It says either the access rights are wrong, or the repo doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Comment: @Froxx First, the URL must use the absolute path: `ssh://ssh-user@server-b.com/absolute/path-to-git-repos/project.git` (note the '`/`' instead of '`:`'). Second, test first your SSH connection with (as user git on serverA) `ssh -T ssh-user@server-b.com`: you should be able to open a connection there.

Comment: Okay, I entered the absolute path as you described. But I can't test the SSH connection like that, because GitLab instantly disconnects the connection after startup. It says `Welcome to GitLab, @user! Connection to server-a closed.`. And when I go for `ssh git@server-a 'ssh -T ssh-user@server-b'` it says `GitLab: Disallowed command` because the Git user really can't do anything on terminal level. Doing the same with the root user instead of the git user works fine. Is there another way to check if it's a url or permission related problem?

Comment: @Froxx your mirroring is done from serverA (where there is GitLab) to serverB (where there is *not* GitLab, if I am not mistaken): so `ssh -T ssh-user@server-b` should work, when done directly from serverA. To connect to server A, you could use another account than git.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. A has GitLab, B doesn't. And like I said, I can connect from A to B when using A's root user, no matter if doing it directly from A or indirectly from my local machine over A. But I think I can't use another user than git on A. The mirror process is triggered by GitLab automatically, and this process is executed by the git user.

Comment: @Froxx if you are connected as root on serverA, you can test SSH connection to serverB with `ssh -i ~git/.ssh/id_rsa ssh-user@server-b`

Comment: Oh, good to know. That works. So the git user's SSH access is correct. My full path entered in the textfield in GitLabs frontend now (only replacing the user, the domain, and the project name) is `ssh://ssh-user@server-b/www/htdocs/ssh-user/git/project.git`. I really can't find the problem there.

Comment: @Froxx As root, to test it further, can you do: `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i  ~git/.ssh/id_rsa'`, and then (still as `root` from serverA) `git clone ssh://ssh-user@server-b/www/htdocs/ssh-user/git/project.git`?

Comment: That also works. I get a new folder `project` with `.git` in it. Just to be sure: `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa'` (without git) resets the variable to the original value, right?

Comment: @Froxx the variable had no original value, and root does not clone repo usually, so it does not matter much. But you can `unset GIT_SSH_COMMAND` if you want.

Comment: @Froxx So now it depends on how git of serverA is using SSH. Does the updated documentation mentions anything about referencing the private key in the repo mirorring settings?

Comment: I see, thanks. Nevertheless I'm heavily wondering why that worked on terminal level, but not when entering it into GitLab's frontend. The url is the exact same one. And no, the docs don't say anything about that (I would heavily wonder about that anyway). Here is the full GitLab error message: `Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: @Froxx Oh, right. Nothing to do with the ssh key itself, only the `~git/.ssh/known_hosts` file (https://askubuntu.com/a/45685/5470). Can you copy the `~root/.ssh/known_hosts` over to `~git/.ssh/known_hosts`? And `chown` it to `git`? And then try again.

Comment: Omg, it finally works! Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: @Froxx No problem. That was a classic ssh issue :)

Comment: @Froxx I have edited the answer to make the various steps found in the comments more visible.