# ansible git clone times out

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-2.x

On a server I can run the following successfully:

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /path/key; git clone https://repo_path/repo_name.git'
```

The repo is cloned into 'repo_name'

However when I run the following ansible (2.2) script on a local machine, the clone task stalls indefinitely

```
- name: clone or pull latest web app code
  git: repo=https://repo_path/repo_name.git dest=/home/user/repo_name
     key_file=/path/key
     accept_hostkey=yes
     force=yes
```

Other tasks prior to the clone taks work ok (apt update, library installs etc)

I am using the following to check the paths are correct, and they seem OK:

```
- debug:
    msg: "about to clone code {{ code_repository }} to {{ base_dir }}"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: `ssh-add /path/key` and  `git clone https://repo_path/repo_name.git` have nothing to do one with another.
`ssh-add /path/key` is for adding a passphrase-protected private SSH key to the ssh-agent, in order to cache said passphrase when it will be needed by an SSH URL.
And `https://repo_path/...` is an HTTPS URL, meaning it does not require the SSH key. At all.

The [ansible git module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_module.html) does mention:

> ```
> accept_hostkey
> ```
>
> if yes, ensure that "`-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`" is present **as an ssh option**.

Again, the URL is HTTPS, so it is not needed.

Try and remove `key-file` and `accept_hostkey`, to see if the HTTPS clone can proceed.

---

For an SSH URL, you need to make sure that:

- the  public key is correctly published on the server side (in `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`),
- and `~/.ssh/known_hosts` is properly updated, [as I have seen yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51226565/6309) with "[SSH connection problem with “Host key verification failed…” error](https://askubuntu.com/a/45685/5470)".

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Yes ssh example I gave I pasted wrong code should have been ssh-agent bash ... git@... Looking at all my other playbooks, I am using repo=ssh//git@repo_path/repo_name.git after using this instead of https I am getting FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/git", "fetch", "--tags", "origin"], "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to download remote objects and refs:  Permission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n"

Comment: @proximacentauri then it could simply be a public key not cirrectly published on the server side (in `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`), or a `~/.ssh/known_hosts` not properly updated, as I have seen yesterday with https://stackoverflow.com/a/51226565/6309 and https://askubuntu.com/a/45685/5470.

Comment: @proximacentauri I have included the last comment in the answer for more visibility.